# The generated sound is 'chopped'

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, audio-streaming, pyaudio

I have code where when you press on midi controller a button (which is mapped to a frequency) the triangle wave is generated for the whole time when is the button pressed. The weird part is that with frequency 440 Hz the sound is continuous but with other frequencies the sound is 'chopped'(intermittent). Any ideas how to solve my problem?

```
import threading
import time
from rtmidi.midiutil import open_midiinput
import numpy as np
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5
fs = 44100
duration = 1.0
fG = 392.00
fA = 440.0
fB = 493.88
fC = 523.25
fD = 587.33

frekvence = 440

frekvence_seznam = {
    (144, 32): fA,
    (144, 33): fB,
    (144, 34): fC,
    (144, 35): fD,
    (144, 36): fG
}

port = 0

midiin, port_name = open_midiinput(port)
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=256)

stop_event = threading.Event()

def sound_play():
    global frekvence
    period = 2 * np.pi
    x = period * np.arange(fs * duration) * frekvence / fs
    triangle = 2/np.pi * np.arcsin(np.sin(x))
    sinus = np.sin(x)

    samples = sinus.astype(np.float32)
    
    vysledek = volume * samples
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        stream.write(vysledek)

    
    # stream.close()
    # p.terminate()

def play_sound():
    global sound
    sound = threading.Thread(target=sound_play)
    sound.start()

while True:
    msg = midiin.get_message()

    if msg:
        message = msg
        klic = message[0]
        lepsi_klic = tuple(klic[:2])
        end_klic = tuple(klic[:1])
        print(message[0])

        if lepsi_klic in frekvence_seznam:
            print("je to tam")
            frekvence = frekvence_seznam[lepsi_klic]
            play_sound()
        elif end_klic == (128,):
            stop_event.set() 
            sound.join()  
            stop_event.clear()  

            print("konec zvuku")
            # break 
        elif lepsi_klic == (144, 81):
            exit()



midiin.close_port()
p.terminate()
exit()
```

Comment: One thing you could do as a test is to have your callback also write the samples it generates into a .wav or .aiff file, and then after your program has generated a several-seconds-long audio file, load that file into Audacity (or similar) and zoom in on the waveform-graph to see what the shape of the waveform looks like.  If you see any unexpected discontinuities in the waveform, those would indicate a problem that will cause distortion in the audio, and you would need to revisit your math to fix that.

Comment: OTOH if the waveform looks okay, then the problem is more likely to be a performance problem (e.g. the audio-output buffer is periodically underrunning, causing brief gaps of silence), and you'd need to instead figure out how to make the routine execute faster to avoid that.